# Marginalizing a Poisson-distributed count parameter in a Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, marginal-distribution, stan

I'm trying to implement the following model in Stan:
$$\begin{align} \text{Pr}(y|n,p) & \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)\\
\text{Pr}(n|\lambda) & \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)
\end{align}$$

In this model, $y$ and $n$ are non-negative integers, $0<p<1$, $\lambda > 0$, and  $y \le n$.  Because Stan does not allow for discrete parameters, I need to marginalize over $n$ (i.e., find the probability mass function of $y$ given $p$ and $\lambda$. The PMFs of $y$ and $n$ are as follows:

$$\begin{align} \text{Pr}(y|n,p) = & \frac{n!}{y!(n-y)!}p^{y}(1-p)^{n-y}\\
\text{Pr}(n|\lambda) =& \frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}\end{align}$$

My attempt to marginalize over $n$ is as follows:

$$\begin{alignat}{4} \text{Pr}(y|p,\lambda) & =  \sum_{n=y}^{\infty}\text{Pr}(y|n,p)\text{Pr}(n|\lambda)\\\\
& = \sum_{n=y}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{y!(n-y)!}p^{y}(1-p)^{n-y}\\\\
& = \frac{e^{-\lambda p}p^{y}\lambda^{y}}{\Gamma(y+1)} \end{alignat} $$

The final step was done by [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3Dy%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Clambda%5E%7Bn%7De%5E%7B-%5Clambda%7D%7D%7By!(n-y)!%7Dp%5E%7By%7D(1-p)%5E%7Bn-y%7D), as my own mathematical skills are a bit rusty. Does this seem correct?

To implement this, I first took the log PMF:

$$\text{log-Pr}(y|p,\lambda)=-\lambda p+y(\text{log}p+\text{log}\lambda)-\text{log}\Gamma(y+1)$$

The Stan code for the function is:

```
  real binomial_poisson_lpmf(int[] y, vector p, vector lambda) { // vectorized;  assumes that y, p, and lambda are all of the same length.
    vector[size(y)] out;
    for(i in 1:size(y))
      out[i] = -lambda[i] * p[i] + y[i] * (log(p[i]) + log(lambda[i])) - lgamma(y[i]+1));
    return(sum(out));
  }
```

Anyway, I would appreciate any feedback on whether or not this seems valid; I would also like to know if anyone knows of any citations on the subject.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the above is accurate, then in theory this should also be applicable when the Poisson is replaced with a Negative binomial (Mean parameterization PMF): $$\text{Pr}(y|p,\mu,\phi)=\sum_{n=y}^{\infty}\frac{p^{y}(1-p)^{n-y}(n+\phi-1)!}{y!(n-y)!(\phi-1)!}(\frac{\mu}{\mu+\phi})^{n}(\frac{\phi}{\mu+\phi})^{\phi}$$

The resulting compounded PMF would be $$\text{Pr}(y|p,\mu,\phi)=\frac{p^{y}(\frac{\mu}{\mu+\phi})^{y}(\frac{\phi}{\mu+\phi})^{\phi}(\frac{p\mu+\phi}{\mu+\phi})^{-(y+\phi)}\Gamma(y+\phi)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(\phi)}$$.

Comment: You have equalities between things that are not equal. Consider using $\propto$ when necessary.

Comment: I suppose $\theta$ and $p$ refer to the same parameter (you may want to edit to fix the notation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### $y \mid p,\lambda$ is Poisson!

Your marginalization, or at least the end result, is correct. The form you have obtained for the distribution is the probability mass function of a Poisson distribution -- just write $p^y\lambda^y$  as $(\lambda\,p)^y$ and behold. That is,

\begin{equation}
y \mid p, \lambda \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda\,p).
\end{equation}

You have essentially rediscovered the fact that a Poisson process thinned randomly (so that every point is selected with probability $p$ independent of others) is Poisson. This is a well-known result, a quick Google turned up [1] but I suppose this is in many textbooks. Your situation is analogous to this, since the Poisson distributed random variable $y$ can be interpreted as the number of arrivals in a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ in a unit interval. Conditional on $y$ the thinning operation selects each of the $y$ points independently with probability $p$, which is a binomial trial.

So, the marginalization could have been 'derived' without any algebraic manipulations by knowing the thinning-of-a-Poisson-process result and realizing how it applies here.

#### Note about Stan implementation

Note that this also means you do not have to write your own function in Stan since this is simply

`y ~ poisson(lambda .* p)`.

#### Negative-binomial case

This extends to the NegBin-case (mentioned in comments), too, since a negative binomial can be represented as a mixture of Poissons where the parameter has a Gamma distribution. Conditional on the gamma-distributed parameter, $y$ is Poisson, too. And if $\lambda$ is gamma-distributed, $p\,\lambda$ is too (fixed $p$), so when marginalizing over the gamma-distributed parameter, $y$ is negative-binomial.

The  negative-binomial has multiple parametrizations -- depending on the parametrization one has to work out how multiplying the Poisson rates by $p$ translates into the parameters of the negative-binomial. Left as an exercise to the reader.

#### Reference

[1] http://www.randomservices.org/random/poisson/Splitting.html -- Random (formerly Virtual Laboratories in Probability and Statistics), Section 13.5

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that.  Your answer was extraordinarily helpful, thank you.